# Nest a JSON object stored in a string variable

Tags: json, sql-server

If I want to pass a JSON string as a variable and embed that within another JSON object using `FOR JSON PATH` in SQL Server, how do I do that?

Condensed example:

```
DECLARE @empInfo nvarchar(max), @msg nvarchar(max)
SET @empInfo = (SELECT '00500' as 'Company', '10000' as 'Employee' FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER)

SET @msg = (
    SELECT
    @empInfo as 'EmployeeInformation',
    'other data' as 'Other Data'
    FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
)
SELECT @msg
```

In this case, @msg will be poorly formatted.  EmployeeInformation **should not** have quotes around it, and characters have been escaped.

```
{"EmployeeInformation":"{\"Company\":\"00500\",\"Employee\":\"10000\"}","Other Data":"other data"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap it in a call to [`JSON_QUERY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-query-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) so it is treated as a JSON object not a string.

```
DECLARE @empInfo nvarchar(max), @msg nvarchar(max)
SET @empInfo = (SELECT '00500' as 'Company', '10000' as 'Employee' FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER)

SET @msg = (
    SELECT
     JSON_QUERY(@empInfo) as 'EmployeeInformation',
    'other data' as 'Other Data'
    FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
)
SELECT @msg
```

**Returns**

```
{
  "EmployeeInformation": {
    "Company": "00500",
    "Employee": "10000"
  },
  "Other Data": "other data"
}
```

**Instead of**

```
{
  "EmployeeInformation": "{\"Company\":\"00500\",\"Employee\":\"10000\"}",
  "Other Data": "other data"
}
```